# Как оптимизировать обновление Dictionary в цикле foreach?

Tags: c#, update, словари

```
class JsonProject
{
    public string Name;
    public List<string> ListQuery = new List<string>();
    ....
}

class JsonHelper
{
    internal static object ReadJsonFile(string path)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
class MyClass
{
    public Dictionary<string, JsonProject> DictProject = new Dictionary<string, JsonProject>();

    public void UpdateDict(string AppProjectPath)
    {
        foreach (string path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(AppProjectPath))
        {
            var project = (JsonProject)JsonHelper.ReadJsonFile(path);
            if (DictProject.ContainsKey(project.Name))
                DictProject[project.Name] = project;
            else DictProject.Add(project.Name, project);
        }
    }
}
```

Хочу оптимизировать - записать по другому эту часть кода:

```
if (DictProject.ContainsKey(project.Name))
    DictProject[project.Name] = project;
else DictProject.Add(project.Name, project);
```

Comment: Что именно вам не нравится в приведённом коде? По какому параметру хотите провести оптимизацию?

Comment: Другой вопрос- вы действительно провели профилирование кода на разных тестах и действительно выяснили что `foreach` является узким местом в данном случае?

Comment: мне не нравится проверка, и присвоение ключу значения, думаю можно сделать по другому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
if (DictProject.ContainsKey(project.Name))
    DictProject[project.Name] = project;
else DictProject.Add(project.Name, project);
```

на

```
DictProject[project.Name] = project;
```

Comment: Вот это я затупил, спасибо .